# PorterDuff Multiply on a path over an ImageView turns transparency into black

Tags: android

I would like to draw a path over an image, and fill that path with a color that uses a PorterDuff multiply xfermode. However, it appears that Android completes the portions of the rectangle containing the path that *should be* transparent with black. This only happens when hardware acceleration is turned on on the activity - when it's off, it works as intended.

[What I want (and what happens with hardware acceleration is off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0YCI.jpg)

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IsWk.jpg)

My (simplified) code so far:

```
public class ImageOverlayTest extends ImageView {

    private Paint mOverlayPaint;
    private Path mOverlayPath;

    public ImageOverlayTest(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mOverlayPaint = new Paint();
        mOverlayPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
        mOverlayPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    protected void createOverlayPath() {
        mOverlayPath = new Path();
        mOverlayPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(0, 400);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(getWidth() / 3, 600);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(getWidth() * 2 / 3, 600);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(getWidth(), 400);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
        mOverlayPath.lineTo(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        createOverlayPath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mOverlayPath, mOverlayPaint);
    }
}
```

Having hardware acceleration off really kills the performance of other aspects of my activities (simple animations), so I need to avoid that. Likewise, an easier, but uglier, solution is to just overlay the color with some transparency, but that's not the effect I'd like.

Thanks for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, you can disable hardware acceleration on the View itself by calling

`setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`